# Tab formatter tool to prepare array data

Tags: arrays, csv, tabbing

Is there a tool that can take this:

```
Attack,Decay,Sustain,Release
45,-1,26,55
"VERY LONG TEXT",false,true,true
0,0,1,1
```

and output it in a tabbed-format like this:

```
Attack,            Decay,  Sustain, Release
45,                -1,     26,      55
"VERY LONG TEXT",  false,  true,    true
0,                 0,      1,       1
```

I need it for some arrays that I'm building with CSV data, I'm currently doing it manually but wondering if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

- Save the comma separated content into
  a text file with .csv extension.
- Open the csv file using excel.
- Save the csv file as "tab separated text" file, into a new file

Or

- Use an editor like notepad++ (any editor that has a bit advanced find/replace capability)
- Find ",", replace with "\t" (and check the option that has a title regular expression)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not `,`->`\t`, but `,`->`,\t`.

Comment: OP wants to replace comma with a tab & hence "," with "\t".

Comment: But your solution does not calculate how many tabs are needed based on the longest cell of the column. Only a specially created script/program can do this. See updated data in my Q.

Comment: If you open the data in excel & make columns autofit, you will be able to see it the way you want it. In that case, you are looking for a way for columns to start at specific position (which is more of a visual thing). Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ column -s, -t
```

This will remove the commas, but those are easy enough to put back.
Perhaps something like:

```
$ column -s, -t < input | perl -pe 's/(\w) /$1,/g'
Attack, Decay, Sustain, Release
45,     -1,    26,      55
false,  false, true,    true
0,      0,     1,       1
```

Of course, this gives you space delimited output.  I just re-read your question and see that you want tabs.  That makes it much easier.  Just do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/,/,\t/g' input
```